# Самая простая инструкция по работе с git

Tags: bitbucket, git, контроль-версий

Я никогда не работал с системами контроля кода. Сейчас подключился к существующему репозиторию на bitbucket для работы с сайтом (при подключении выбрал clone). Про эти системы есть множество статей, но они изобилуют разными подробностями, которые мне на данный момент не нужны. Я не использую командную строку и не работаю с файлами локально (использую редактор Coda и правлю прямо на сервере по ftp). Мне нужна самая простая инструкция: я изменил файл, что дальше делать, чтобы сохранить изменения в репозитории? Я думал что нужно нажать для этого Commit, но данный пункт в меню у меня почему-то неактивен, активны только Push/Pull changes to/from origin, но Push у меня не работает так как я ожидал (а ожидал я что потом если нажать Pull, то файл восстановится до моего измененного состояния, но он восстановился до состояния до того, как я его менял). В списке branches я выбрал master.

Comment: Кнопка commit была неактивной, потому что я менял файл через ftp, а чтобы запихать такой файл в репозиторий, нужно его сначала скачать на локальную копию.

Comment: если еще актуально :), то вот же оно: http://goloburdin.blogspot.com/2013/11/git-bitbucket-20.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Git - распределенная система, репозиторий на компьютере и сервере - это два совершенно разных репозитория, и push/pull просто синхронизирует эти репозитории по сети. При работе с репозиторием (оставим пока синхронизацию в стороне) нужны три команды - `git add` добавляет файлы к следующему коммиту (операция называется `stage`, команда для обратной операции - `git rm --cached %file%`), `git commit` записывает изменения отдельным коммитом, `git reset` выполняет простой откат к выбранному коммиту (здесь я сам плаваю), `git revert` похож на `git reset`, только его изменения могут быть представлены коммитом (в то время как ресет просто откатывается к некоторому коммиту). Таким образом обычный flow может выглядеть так:

```
geany superfile.py
geany secondfile.py
git add . # указывается директория или файл
git commit -m "Commit message" # Без сообщения в том или ином виде ничего не уйдет
```

После того, как локальный репозитарий изменился, его можно отправлять на remote

```
git push -u origin master # отправляем ветвь master на remote c название origin  и выставляем его главным. Мастер-ветку вроде бы можно и не указывать
```

В следующий раз уже достаточно будет сделать просто git push

```
git push
```

И все новые коммиты (но не изменения) уйдут на сервер.

`git pull` сольет с сервера репозиторий в том виде, который он есть, и, скорее всего, затрет имеющиеся изменения (если над ними не была произведена операция `stage` - в этом случае `git` откажется выполнять операцию до тех пор, пока `stage-area` не опустеет или ключ `--force` не заставит это сделать).

**Long story short**

1. Создаются / меняются файлы
2. Файлы добавляются к грядущему коммиту c помощью `git add %path%`
3. Совершается коммит `git commit`, если не указывать ключ -m, то вылезет редактор, где нужно будет вписать сообщение с описанием изменений
4. `git push` отправляет свежие коммиты на сервер
5. `git pull` вытягивает репу в состоянии последнего коммита на сервере

---

- Уже сделанный, но не отправленный коммит можно поправить с помощью команды `git commit --amend`. Уже отправленный коммит тоже можно, но **ни в коем случае не надо этого делать**, ничего страшного, если исправления улетят следующим.
- Ненужные файлы исключаются из коммитов с помощью файла `.gitignore`. Можно один раз настроить его на игнорирование всяких `*.log`, `*.pyc` и прочего мусора, а потом безопасно делать `git add .`.
- IDE очень часто будет смешивать команды git add и git commit до неразличимости

На самом деле книга по гиту объясняет все очень доступным языком: http://git-scm.com/book/ru/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B-Git-%D0%97%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%81%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B9-%D0%B2-%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B9
Поэтому, возможно, стоит вообще пропустить этот пост и сразу лезть туда.

Ну и последнее. Git может быть (и будет) сложен, но это только к лучшему, это очень гибкая система.

Comment: Спасибо, но не совсем то, о чем я спрашивал :) Меня не интересует командная строка и теория, именно поэтому я этот вопрос и задал, ключевое слово в нем - ПРОСТАЯ. Лично я считаю, что можно много найти интересных занятий, если не хочется заниматься непосредственно делом - и системы контроля кода далеко не лучший выбор в этом плане. Просто требованием заказчика по одному проекту является работа с git, и мне нужно только знать как эти несчастные файлы, которые я поменял, запихать в репозиторий :) Хотя что может быть сложного в автоматическом бекапе с парой доп. функций, я тоже не понимаю.

Comment: @baduga я не знаком с конкретно этим редактором. Но суть от этого сильно не меняется: файлы добавляются в `stage area` - делается коммит - коммит отправляется на сервер (push). Перед коммитом необходимо делать pull, чтобы избежать конфликтов.
И да, без изучения некоторой теории (тут ее минимум) будет сложно.

Comment: Собственно вот этого ответа я и ждал - нужно нажать кнопку Commit, потом Push. Ну все-таки, что в этом сложного - нажать две кнопки, и зачем тут вообще теория?))) Если я правильно понял, то Stage Area - это локальная копия сайта или что-то вроде кеша?

Comment: @baduga ближе к кэшу. Копия тех файлов, которые должны уйти на коммит. В IDE про нее обычно можно не помнить, так как она создается и тут же улетает на коммит.